# Raw Sockets in TCL

Tags: sockets, network-programming, tcl

I would like to use raw socket implentation in TCl as it is used in Python and C, is this possible? Does the TCL socket library even support raw sockets?

Python Raw Socket Example:

```
#create a raw socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

# tell kernel not to put in headers, since we are providing it, when using IPPROTO_RAW this is not necessary
# s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# now start constructing the packet
packet = '';

source_ip = '192.168.1.101'
dest_ip = '127.0.0.1' # or socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')

# ip header fields
ip_ihl = 5
ip_ver = 4
ip_tos = 0
ip_tot_len = 0  # kernel will fill the correct total length
ip_id = 54321   #Id of this packet
ip_frag_off = 0
ip_ttl = 255
ip_proto = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
ip_check = 0    # kernel will fill the correct checksum
ip_saddr = socket.inet_aton ( source_ip )   #Spoof the source ip address if you want to
ip_daddr = socket.inet_aton ( dest_ip )

ip_ihl_ver = (ip_ver << 4) + ip_ihl

# the ! in the pack format string means network order
ip_header = pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_ihl_ver, ip_tos, ip_tot_len, ip_id, ip_frag_off, ip_ttl, ip_proto, ip_check, ip_saddr, ip_daddr)

# tcp header fields
tcp_source = 1234   # source port
tcp_dest = 80   # destination port
tcp_seq = 454
tcp_ack_seq = 0
tcp_doff = 5    #4 bit field, size of tcp header, 5 * 4 = 20 bytes
#tcp flags
tcp_fin = 0
tcp_syn = 1
tcp_rst = 0
tcp_psh = 0
tcp_ack = 0
tcp_urg = 0
tcp_window = socket.htons (5840)    #   maximum allowed window size
tcp_check = 0
tcp_urg_ptr = 0

tcp_offset_res = (tcp_doff << 4) + 0
tcp_flags = tcp_fin + (tcp_syn << 1) + (tcp_rst << 2) + (tcp_psh <<3) + (tcp_ack << 4) + (tcp_urg << 5)

# the ! in the pack format string means network order
tcp_header = pack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_source, tcp_dest, tcp_seq, tcp_ack_seq, tcp_offset_res, tcp_flags,  tcp_window, tcp_check, tcp_urg_ptr)

user_data = 'Hello, how are you'
```

I cut out some parts but you get the idea. Is this possible?

Comment: See http://wiki.tcl.tk/16733 and http://community.activestate.com/forum/newbie-tcl-how-program-using-sockets.

Comment: Tcl doesn't have built-in support for datagram-oriented sockets of any type, which would be necessary for doing RAW sockets. (Also, RAW sockets are usually restricted to “trusted” processes on Unix; they're very abusable, alas.) It's unlikely to change before [TIP #409](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/409.html) is addressed, but [Scotty](http://wiki.tcl.tk/691) might be relevant. Not sure…

Comment: You might be interested in HPING3 too. http://www.hping.org/manpage.html

Answer (score 0):

I did some more looking, ceptcl was written to add some Raw socket functionality to Tcl. I will use it if I can't find anything better. http://wiki.tcl.tk/11140